# "Sounds like/as an excuse"

Tags: as-like

Which expression is the correct one, with respect to the bolded word?

> **A**: That sounds **as** an excuse to me.
>   **B**: That sounds **like** an excuse to me.

Are they both correct?  Neither?

Comment: I think this is hardly off-topic. The question is perfectly understandable as it is. Are askers expected to say how much effort they have put in for their questions to be answered? I find this absurd. It seems to me that the community will not accept a question for which they can't agree on an answer, and prefer to rule it out as "on hold".

Comment: @Gustavson It's closed for lack of context/research, not because of disagreement on an answer. That said, "as" and "like" are tricky and I don't think it's easy to find authoritative answers to which one is better in a particular sentence, so I lean toward reopening this one.

Comment: I'm glad you are in favor of reopening it. I think the alleged lack of context or research merely served **as an excuse** not to face the fact that it was difficult to come up with a good answer.

Comment: @Gustavson - I agree; sometimes we are a little too quick to closevote a question without really considering how challenging it might be for a learner. That said, the answer to your "Are askers expected to say how much effort they have put in?" question, I've always recommended that approach – generally speaking, it's a good way to ward off downvotes and closevotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both correct, but "as an excuse" is more old-fashioned and rarely used these days. Because of this, most people would use "like an excuse" as the default option.

Comment: "It sounds like an excuse" is a cliche. If a cliche is a default option, then yes, you're right. "As an excuse", old-fashioned or not, is far more frequently used, IMHO. See the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+an+excuse%2C+like+an+excuse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20an%20excuse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20an%20excuse%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Isn't there a tacit implication that, in the case of (A), "I" thinks that what was said was actually an excuse while in the case of (B) "I" knows that whatever was said sounded like an excuse but was not one? (A is justified, B is not) Compare: *work **as** a slave / work **like** a slave*

Comment: @Rompey I can't remember a time when someone has said "That sounds as an excuse" to me. It might just be where I'm from, but I would always say "like an excuse". The google NGram viewer looks at books. In speech, "Like an excuse" is far more common in my experience.

Comment: @Gustavson In the excuse example, they have the same meaning. In your example, the word "work" changes the meaning, since "work as something" has its own different meaning. "sounds as something" does not have this change in meaning, making it the same as "sounds like something".

Comment: @AricFowler I know that the difference is more clearcut with *work*, but what I meant to say is that *as* usually carries a meaning of equivalence while *like* is more likely to convey the idea of similarity: sth that seems to be but is not.